# More tolerable feign client

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-feign

I am the feign client to fetch a list of comics from the Marvel Api. But a doubt arose, I created a MarvelComicsResponse class adding the attributes that I want to print in postman. I have an attribute called issueNumber of type Long and today MarvelApi returns me a numerical value, if by chance the MarvelApi devs change the issueNumber return from a numerical value to a String, I will possibly have an error in my application that will break it . My doubt is, is there any way I can make my application more tolerable using the feign client, that is, if MarvelApi changes the return type from numeric to String, I want my application to just ignore it instead of breaking it, until I to be able to make the necessary adjustments, is it possible?

I would like to know if it is possible, if so I would like to see an example or some article or documentation about it please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.